# reset Android FrameLayout object to "clean" state

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-framelayout, object-pooling

I am trying to implement my own Android view recycling.  My question is, is there a simple way to "reset" an Android View object (more specifically, a FrameLayout) to the state in which it would come out of a constructor.  In other words, it knows about its context, but it's forgotten about things like calls to SetWillNotDraw, touch handlers, visibility, or anything else I may have set on it.

The alternative would be to write my own "reset" method.  I'm concerned that if I go that route, I will end up with bugs relating to failing to reset some portion of the state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't.  If you weren't trying to do recycling I'd suggest just creating a new one is the easiest way to ensure it.  Its also not a very efficient thing to do in general-  there's a lot of pieces of state that can be changed, if you try to set all of them you'll end up wasting a lot of cycles.  Generally you have the code that sets these things have a reset method of some sort called when you unbind a view from its model, and it will clear the subset of things it changed.